# What are the associated prime ideals of rees ring?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $I$ be an ideal of $R$ and $R[It]$ be a rees ring of $R$ with respect to $I$. Do we have $Ass R[It]=\{pR[It] : p\in Ass(R)\}$? if not what can we say?

($Ass(R)$ is the associated prime ideals of $R$).